# API xlwt on python excel report

Tags: python, xlwt

I was able to get it working on adding api on to Excel file. I'm confused how can I another api query so that it will be on the next line of Ticket Update after its finish. Because the item of the file will be different every time. I'm confused how to do it.

May you please give me example :

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("Ticket Updated", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
ws.write(0, 0, 'Ticket Updated', style0)
ws.write(1, 0, 'KEY', style0)
ws.write(1, 1, 'SUMMARY', style0)
ws.write(1, 2, 'ASSIGN', style0)
ws.write(1, 3, 'REPORTER',style0)
ws.write(1, 4, 'STATUS',style0)
ws.write(1, 5, 'RESOLUTION', style0)
ws.write(1, 6, 'CREATE DATE', style0)
ws.write(1, 7, 'UPDATE DATE', style0)
ws.write(1, 8, 'DUE', style0)
ws.write(1, 9, 'SERVICE TEAM', style0)



row = 2

for issue in responses['issues']:
issue_fields = issue['fields']
issue_status = issue_fields['status']
issue_reporter = issue_fields['reporter']['displayName']
issue_created = issue_fields['created']
issue_updated = issue_fields['updated']
issue_assign = 'Unassigned'
issue_resolution = 'Unassigned'
issue_due = 'null'
issue_serviceteam = 'null'
issue_createdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_created[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")
issue_updatedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_updated[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")
  if issue_fields['assignee']:
      issue_assign = issue_fields['assignee']['displayName']
  if issue_fields['resolution']:
       issue_resolution = issue_fields['resolution']['name']
  if issue_fields.get('duedate', None):
       issue_due = issue_fields['duedate']
  if issue_fields.get('customfield_10506', None):
       issue_serviceteam = issue_fields['customfield_10506']['name']

   ws.write(row, 0, issue['key'])
   ws.write(row, 1, issue_fields['summary'])
   ws.write(row, 2, issue_assign)
   ws.write(row, 3, issue_reporter)
   ws.write(row, 4, issue_status['name'])
   ws.write(row, 5, issue_resolution)
   ws.write(row, 6, issue_createdate)
   ws.write(row, 7, issue_updatedate)
   ws.write(row, 8, issue_due)
   ws.write(row, 9, issue_serviceteam)

   row += 1

   wb.save("excell.xls")
```

Comment: Could you please try simplify your question? Perhaps try to specify to which part of your code sample it is mostly related? And if possible I see space for reduction of your sample - it doesn't have to be exact code you are using.

Comment: I trying to add another api example: Ticketlastweek and get the data and export it and add it automatically on the next cell. My problem is the this code doesn't have fix output. May you please give me sample how can i do this.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see "Ticketlastweek" anywhere. Your comment did not clarify anyhting to me.

Comment: Is your aim to append new data to the end of an existing Excel file each time you run your script? If so, you will need to read the existing one in first.

Comment: Hello Martin,Yes your correct

Comment: i already got it thanks